# How can I build a git tag on Openshift Origin?

Tags: git, openshift, openshift-origin, okd, buildconfig

How can create `BuildConfig` to build an specific git tag on Openshift Origin?

I did not found on [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/dev_guide/builds.html)

I have tried `commit` and `tag`like following:

```
  source:
    type: Git
    git:
      uri: 'https://github.com/luiscoms/gravity-world.git'
      ref: master
      commit: 1.0.0
      tag: 1.0.0
```

With tag:

```
  source:
    type: Git
    git:
      uri: 'https://github.com/luiscoms/gravity-world.git'
      ref: master
      tag: 1.0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the tag in the "ref" property (a tag is global to a repository)

```
source:
    type: Git
    git:
      uri: 'https://github.com/luiscoms/gravity-world.git'
      ref: myTag_1.0.0
```

This is openshift documentation reference:

"*The git field contains the URI to the remote Git repository of the source code. Optionally, specify the ref field to check out a specific Git reference. **A valid ref can be a SHA1 [commit hash], tag, or a branch name**.*"

https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/dev_guide/builds.html#source-code

Comment: From what I have read you can only use a tag in the vcs-ref for the master/main origin branch? Ho do I specify a specific tag on a different branch?